# How to print a random word from a list which ends with 's'?

Tags: python, random

So I'm trying to figure out how to run a script that searches for a random word ending in 's'. the txt list I'm using is 50% words ending in 's'. I have tried a few things and I can't seem to figure it out.
basically what I want it to do is run 'snoun' and tell it hits a word ending in s. I'm sure there are other ways to achieve this one thing, but the process itself is relatively important.
right now I'm getting `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.

```
X = random.randint(1,218)
file = open('pluralnoun.txt')
content = file.readlines()
snoun = content[X]
def nouns():
    if snoun == "*s":
        print(snoun)
    else:
        nouns()
```

After seeing a comment I realize of course it won't work. So I tried

```
def run():
    X = random.randint(1,218)
    file = open('pluralnoun.txt')
    content = file.readlines()
    snoun = content[X]
    if snoun == "*s":
        print(snoun)
    else:
        run()
```

and I am getting
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: you have a problem, if `if` condition is false, you run into infinite recursion call at `nouns()`

Comment: Why you call `nouns()` if the snoun is not endwith "s"? The snoun is never change

Comment: The way to test if something ends is 's' isn't `snoun == "*s"`.  That tests if the string is literally the two characters "asterisk" and "ess".

Comment: Maybe you should just make a list of words ending in `s` and [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) one from the list. You can use `word.endswith('s')` to find them.

Comment: assuming content is a list, `[x for x in content if x[-1] == 's']`; and also can remove if condition.

Comment: @Mark mainly just because im messing around with this trying to learn how to sift through data and find specific things. Its more useful in the long run for me

Answer (score 3):

Create a list of words ending in `s` and then randomly sample a value from the list.

```
import random

with open('pluralnoun.txt') as f:
    words = [x for x in file.read().splitlines() if x.endswith('s')]

snoun = random.choice(words)
```

Just for the heck of it, a regex way could look like:

```
import random
import re

with open('pluralnoun.txt') as f:
    words = re.findall('(\w+s)\s', f.read())

snoun = random.choice(words)
```

Comment: Cause `sample` came to mind first, `choice` is definitely better.

Comment: i am getting an error with with the first one "import random
import re

with open('pluralnoun.txt') as f:
    words = re.findall('(\w+s)\s', f.read())

snoun = random.choice(words)"

Comment: regex works perfectly though

Comment: @Bryan made a small modification to deal with the newline char at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion happens when you call the function from inside the function. Python has a limit of how deep you can go with your recursion calls. If you want to know how deep python goes, you can do this (`sys` is a builtin module):

```py
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit()
```

Your method of repeatedly trying random numbers using recursion and checking if they end in `s` will work, but it is slow. It is slow because you don't know how long the randomizing will take for it to reach a word ending in `s`. But, for the learning experience, let's try it.

```
file = open('pluralnoun.txt')
content = file.readlines()

def nouns():
    X = random.randint(1,218)
    snoun = content[X]
    if snoun.endswith("s"):
        print(snoun)
    else:
        nouns()

nouns()
```

Reasons why your current method doesn't work:

- `snoun == "*s"`: You are trying to use regular expressions, but that is not the right way to use it. A more pythonic way to do it (without regex) would be `snoun.endswith("s")` When you are checking whether `snoun == "*s"`, you are actually checking for whether `snoun` is letter for letter the same as `"*s"`, which it is probably not.
- `snoun` stays consistent: Since `snoun` is not changing, `snoun == "*s"` will always return the same thing, False, resulting in `nouns` being called again, which means infinite recursion.

So although this method works, it is not good. Because in the worst case, `random.randint` is never going to find a word which ends in `s`, resulting in infinite recursion.

One way to fix this would be by gathering a list of words which end in `s` and then picking a random one out of those. This takes consistently the same time, going through the entire list once, and then picking a random one. Let's do it:

BeRT2me already came up with the solution while I was writing this:

```py
import random

with open("pluralnoun.txt") as f:
    words = [i for i in f.readlines() if i.endswith("s")]

snoun = random.choice(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

words = []

with open("pluralnoun.txt") as file:
   for word in file.readlines():
      if word.lower().endswith("s"):
         words.append(word)

snoun = random.choice(words)
```

Here we use word.lower() to make the code non-case sensitive.

So it will work for both Capital and Smaller case letters.